# Exposing child events to the parent

Tags: onclick, event-handling, react-native

Im trying to handle the child click event of a button in the parent element in React Native.
Im very new to react native so please forgive any book mistakes :)

```
// my transparent button child

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: Theme.button.borderColor,
        borderWidth: Theme.button.borderWidth,
        borderRadius: Theme.button.buttonRadius,
        fontFamily: Theme.button.fontFamily,
        fontWeight: Theme.button.fontWeight,
        color: Theme.button.fontColor
    }
})

var handleClick = function() {
  console.log('You clicked: ');
}

const TransparentButton = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var boundClick = handleClick.bind(this);
        return (
            <Button
                style={styles.button}
                textStyle={styles.button}
                onPress={boundClick}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Button>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = TransparentButton;

// and this is the snippent that is trying to catch the click event
class Welcome extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Page
            style={styles.container}
            backgroundColor={Theme.bgColor}>

                <TransparentButton
                    handleClick={() => console.log('hello there outter')}>
                    Ryans Text Button
                </TransparentButton>
            </Page>
        )
    }
}
```

The inner event click registers fine but the outter event never happenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the TransparentButton you don't call the parent function.

```
const TransparentButton = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                style={styles.button}
                textStyle={styles.button}
                onPress={this.props.handleClick}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Button>
        );
    }
});
```

The es6 way is almost identical and it's better to be consistent across the code, not mix es5 and es6:

```
export default TransparentButton extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                style={styles.button}
                textStyle={styles.button}
                onPress={this.props.handleClick}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Button>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: I just wanted to know is this the best way to set if out? and which would be better? to set this out as a creatClass or to extend the Button its self?

Comment: and if i extended the button the how would i return the button view to the parent with click etc to the parent in the TransParentButton render function?

Comment: thank you very much for your speedy and great response